# Userform initialize checks then close

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform. The idea is to check if there are any 'True' values in column(15) in 'Admin' sheet. If there is at least a single 'True' value, then the userform will remain open and continue its operation.

However, if there is not a single 'True' found, then the userform will display a message and close the userform automatically.

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()

    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Admin")
        For i = 7 To LR
            If .Cells(i, 15) = "True" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                MsgBox ("No values found")
                Exit For
                Unload Me
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    ''' more code'''
End Sub
```

Everything on my userform works as expected, except for the fact I am unable to make it close itself automatically. I.e. **Unload Me** is not working.

Any advice?

Comment: Note that when code is properly indented and spaced, it's much easier to understand what's going on.   I'd suggest you find an alternative using `Exit For`, and also make sure that all your variables are declared by putting `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always].  Also instead of having a form open that doesn't need to display in some cases, check *first* if it needs to display *before* opening it.  *"1. Get a glass of water. 2. Am I thirsty? If not, dump out water."*  :-)

Comment: `Initialize` runs when the class is instantiated. If you're showing the default instance, it may or may not run at all, depending on how it was last closed. `Unload Me` wouldn't be needed at all if you weren't using the default instance. Also unloading an object that's in the process of being constructed, doesn't strike me as a good idea either. Lastly, any code after an `Exit` statement can't be expected to run. You need to review your control flow, something's off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your criteria before you even display the `UserForm`. You can add this as a condition wherever you are calling the `UserForm`. No need to open the form just to immediately close it when you can check before-hand.

On the first instance of `True`, the `UserForm` will open, and exit the sub. If the loop completes (finds no `True` values), the sub will proceed to your `MsgBox`

```
Sub OpenForm

With Worksheets("Admin")
    For i = 7 To LR
       If Cells(i,15) = "True" then 
         Userform.Show
         Exit Sub
       End If
    Next i
End With

MsgBox "No Values Found"

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah - so you do not do this on Initialize... why not?

Comment: It sounds like you want to check some values to determine if you want to keep your user form open or not. I'm assuming your values are determined (set) when the form is opened so you can go either way. Just makes more sense to check before so the form does not have to continuously open/close if your condition is not met.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at your code; you have put Unload Me is after Exit For

```
    'Here is something for you to ponder on .........


    'Public enum type to add a set of particular vbKeys to the standard key set
    Public Enum typePressKeys
        vbNoKey = 0
        vbExitTrigger = -1
        vbAnswerKey = 100
        vbLaunchKey = 102
        vbPrevious = 104
        vbNext = 106
        vbSpecialAccessKey = 108
    End Enum

    Public Sub doSomethingWithMyUserform()
    Dim stopLoop As Boolean, testVal As Boolean, rngX As Range, LR As Long

    LR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngX = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Admin")
    testVal = False
    With rngX 'Your sub can do the check here
        For i = 7 To LR
           If .Cells(i, 15) = "True" Then
                testVal = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If testVal Then
        Load UserForm1
        With UserForm1
            .Caption = "Something"
            .Tag = vbNoKey
            .button_OK.SetFocus 'Assuming you have a OK button on Userform1
        End With
        UserForm1.Show
        stopLoop = False
        Do
            If UserForm1.Tag = vbCancel Then
                'Do something perhaps
                Unload UserForm1
                stopLoop = True
            ElseIf UserForm1.Tag = vbOK Then
                'Do something specific
                Unload UserForm1
                stopLoop = True
            Else
                stopLoop = False
            End If
        Loop Until stopLoop = True
    else
       MsgBox "No values found"
    End If

    'Here you can close the way you want
    Set rngX = Nothing

    End Sub

        enter code here
```

Comment: If I put Unload Me before Exit For, it will continue looping.. and display message n times.

Comment: @OdaySalim point is, `Unload Me` in the `Initialize` handler makes no sense whatsoever. Moreover, *any code* after an `Exit` statement can't be expected to run either. Stop using the forms' default instance (i.e. `New` up your forms instead of doing `UserForm1.Show`), and you'll never need `Unload Me` anyway.